# Parse URL with Regex C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am getting the current URL with:

```
   string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
//url = blahblahblah.aspx?NUMBER=8798494651&FULLNAME=Ronald
```

After this, I want to use `url.Split()` to obtain the value after both equals signs. This would normally be straight forward but as you can see the first value has an obvious end character of '&' while the other does not. Furthermore, the FULLNAME value can always be different.

I have seen other Regex parsing questions/answers on here but of course they are all for specific cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9433/Understanding-CGI-with-C

Comment: Why not you retrieve value as:::
 var num = Request.QueryString["NUMBER"];
 var name= Request.QueryString["FULLNAME"];

Comment: @DCODE I tried that. It was not picking up the values. I would get an error that way. That is why I am thinking of parsing the current url instead

Comment: @JonathanScialpi then try option as below

Comment: @JonathanScialpi What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var uri = new Uri("blahblahblah.aspx?NUMBER=8798494651&FULLNAME=Ronald");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

var var1 = query.Get("NUMBER");
var var2 = query.Get("FULLNAME");
```

Comment: that worked well thanks @DCODE