# C# Selecting part of string when there is a matching result in part of the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, substring

I have a string which basically looks like this:

```
/giveaway/host/setup/ref=aga_h_su_dp?_encoding=UTF8&amp;value_id=1484778065
```

The trick here is that the length of the string can vary and will change... However the part with "value_id=something" always stays same... So the problem that I ran in was that I can do something like this:

```
var myId = string.SubString(30,45);

to get the value after value_id= /*this one here*/
```

I'm thinking that this can be solved by regex or some other way, but I'm not too sure how to write such one. Can someone help me out?

Comment: split by '=' then get last index of your string array

Comment: @arslanaybars what if there are multiple '=' signs in string ?

Comment: isn't it always and of the string ? @User987

Comment: Use the Uri class.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Could you show me an example of that ?

Comment: @User987 seems like it is a part of an url. So no need for string operations. `var value = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input))["value_id"];`

Comment: @User987; take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772271/parse-url-with-regex-c-sharp#32772437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this. If your value_id always the last of your string you can use this.

```
var str = "/giveaway/host/setup/ref=aga_h_su_dp?_encoding=UTF8&amp;value_id=1484778065";

var valueId = str.Split('=').LastOrDefault();
```

Result : 1484778065

Hope it's help to you

Answer (score 0):

You can split by 'value_id='

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(new[] { "value_id=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

if(tokens.Length>1){
   //parse tokens[1] with the value
}
```

Comment: good approach. @User987 you can use this also.

Comment: @arslanaybars would this work if there are multiple = ?

Comment: It will work, but if value_id= is the last. If you have other data after the value you need to separate it, then split again with the separator.